# Install script MySQL syntax error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; [...] "

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have an install script on my website, and when i run it, it gives me thsi error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `active_guests` ( `ip` varchar(15) collate latin1_general_' at line 2

Here is the code where it seems to bug:

```
$sql = 'SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
        CREATE TABLE `active_guests` (
          `ip` varchar(15) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
          `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`ip`)
        );'; 

mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `active_users` (
           `username` varchar(30) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
           `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
        );';

mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `banned_users` (
           `username` varchar(30) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
           `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
        );';
```

It continues even more after that, but basically it's this. Anyone could clear things up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only run one statement per call to `mysql_query()`.

So you have to run `SET SQL_MODE ...` and then separately run the first `CREATE TABLE ...`

---

Re your comment:  I recommend that you stick with running one statement per call to `mysql_query()` or its equivalent in mysqli or PDO.  There's really no significant downside to doing it, and it's a good way to prevent some forms of [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thanks! I've heard about something like mysqli to run more than one statement at once... I might look into it! thanks again!